# How a channel creator that deleted his account in Telegram, can became the creator of same channel?

Tags: telegram, administrator

A person with ID @person and MOB +969123456789 has a channel named TEST in Telegram (for example).
This channel has 3 administrator.
@person, unintentionally deactivate his account. This means creator of channel deleted.
How @person can became the creator of same channel now?

Comment: Anyone can help us?

Comment: **stackoverflow** is not app review forum ,  This is not the right place for asking this question  . you can ask in : https://stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as I know there is no such possibility. This is a Telegram platform shortage and you FOREVER miss all creator privileges as soon as the creator account deletes.

P.S: I've contacted Telegram support regarding this issue several times but they never replied. It looks like they would rather be more interested in developing fancy features(like games, etc) compared to solving critical platform shortages.

Comment: Sadly I have the same problem and I cannot solve this too.

Comment: Here is a official message on twitter about the status of this feature: https://twitter.com/telegram/status/788688065317535744

Comment: In the new version, the features of the new Telegram bot are written:
• Transfer Bot ownership to another account. (https://t.me/BotNews/56)
We can expect the next move to be about channels.